# read a text file in R

Tags: r, fread, read.table

It sounds stupid ! but I could not find a proper way to read [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16uYFPn6VXo7i4oJI5boNDYnULMVkRURW) text file.
I have tried read.table and fread functions. But no success, the columns are not matches with the data :

```
m = fread(meq,fill = T,sep = " ")
m = read.table(meq,fill = T,comment.char="-",sep = "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution :

```
    read.table(text = mgsub::mgsub(readLines(meq),c("\\|", " e","  e"),c("","e","e")),fill = T,comment.char = "-",sep = "",na.strings ="", stringsAsFactors= F,skip = 2)
          V1          V2         V3         V4         V5         V6        V7        V8         V9       V10        V11
1  W<f6>hler      slope:        3.5        4.0        5.0        8.0       8.0      10.0      10.25      12.4      14.95
2  Reference     cycles: 10000000.0 10000000.0 10000000.0 10000000.0 2000000.0 2000000.0 2000000.00 2000000.0 2000000.00
3          1           t      279.1      307.1      351.1      429.2     524.8     539.1     540.50     550.3     558.50
4          2  v_hor_size        6.6        6.8        7.3        9.6      11.8      13.3      13.40      14.9      16.40
5          3   Elevation        4.1        4.1        4.3        5.1       6.2       6.7       6.70       7.3       7.90
6          4   Mf_xe.1n1       43.8       61.4      106.6      270.0     330.2     447.4     461.30     573.9     689.90
7          5   Mf_ye.1n1      107.1      148.0      236.8      493.8     603.8     746.3     762.00     881.7     994.30
8          6  Mf_xye.1n1       71.7       98.6      156.9      324.7     397.0     488.6     498.60     574.4     644.80
9          7 Mf_000e.1n1      107.1      148.0      236.8      493.8     603.8     746.3     762.00     881.7     994.30
10         8 Mf_030e.1n1       99.6      137.2      219.7      460.4     563.0     698.3     713.30     828.3     938.10
11         9 Mf_060e.1n1       72.4      100.6      165.6      371.9     454.8     581.1     595.50     706.6     814.60
12        10 Mf_090e.1n1       43.8       61.4      106.6      270.0     330.2     447.4     461.30     573.9     689.90
13        11 Mf_120e.1n1       56.1       78.5      130.2      302.2     369.5     486.4     500.10     610.4     722.30
14        12 Mf_150e.1n1       90.6      125.8      202.9      429.6     525.4     653.7     668.00     777.4     882.00
15        13   Mf_xe.2n1     2591.1     2521.6     2510.2     2854.9    3491.1    3777.4    3819.20    4199.4    4652.10
16        14   Mf_ye.2n1     1407.2     1385.4     1606.3     2993.9    3661.1    4509.0    4603.60    5327.9    6016.10
17        15  Mf_xye.2n1     2337.5     2239.9     2157.8     2262.2    2766.3    3002.7    3045.10    3432.6    3845.10
18        16 Mf_000e.2n1     1407.2     1385.4     1606.3     2993.9    3661.1    4509.0    4603.60    5327.9    6016.10
19        17 Mf_030e.2n1     1692.9     1668.5     1798.8     2846.6    3480.9    4238.0    4325.60    5008.6    5674.50
20        18 Mf_060e.2n1     2298.1     2247.6     2275.5     2781.8    3401.7    3849.5    3909.90    4430.1    5003.00
21        19 Mf_090e.2n1     2591.1     2521.6     2510.2     2854.9    3491.1    3777.4    3819.20    4199.4    4652.10
22        20 Mf_120e.2n1     2410.8     2334.5     2300.9     2561.2    3132.0    3411.9    3457.50    3902.0    4461.90
23        21 Mf_150e.2n1     1862.8     1799.9     1810.7     2631.1    3217.5    3955.5    4040.70    4700.3    5339.30
24        22   Mf_xe.3n1     6414.2     6261.0     6252.6     7146.9    8739.6    9466.1    9570.50   10506.0   11580.60
```

Answer (score 2):

That file contains some metadata at the top and isn't in a standard format which can be parsed as a dataframe easily. One solution is to read it in as a character vector, do some manipulations, and then read in the resulting file:

```
meq <- "LS_FLS_YUN_IECED3_Tower_100pctAv.meq"

lines <- readLines(meq)

lines <- lines[-(1:5)]

lines <- gsub("\\|", "", lines)

lines <- gsub(" +", " ", lines)

file <- tempfile()

writeLines(lines, file)

data.table::fread(file, sep = " ", fill = TRUE)
#      V1         V2    V3      V4      V5      V6      V7      V8      V9     V10     V11     V12
#  1:   1          t 279.1   307.1   351.1   429.2   524.8   539.1   540.5   550.3   558.5      NA
#  2:   2 v_hor_size   6.6     6.8     7.3     9.6    11.8    13.3    13.4    14.9    16.4      NA
#  3:   3  Elevation   4.1     4.1     4.3     5.1     6.2     6.7     6.7     7.3     7.9      NA
#  4:   4       Mf_x e.1n1    43.8    61.4   106.6   270.0   330.2   447.4   461.3   573.9   689.9
#  5:   5       Mf_y e.1n1   107.1   148.0   236.8   493.8   603.8   746.3   762.0   881.7   994.3
# ---                                                                                             
#766: 766     Mt_030 e13n2  5694.5  5524.4  5559.4  6850.9  8377.6  9381.7  9510.6 10592.5 11771.5
#767: 767     Mt_060 e13n2  9223.2  8757.3  8448.3  9210.8 11263.4 11821.5 11901.7 12606.0 13398.2
#768: 768     Mt_090 e13n2 11582.0 10912.8 10380.1 10898.0 13326.5 13686.1 13745.4 14298.0 14960.4
#769: 769     Mt_120 e13n2 11658.8 11015.8 10529.9 11142.4 13625.4 13989.1 14046.3 14564.8 15166.2
#770: 770     Mt_150 e13n2  9386.4  8973.3  8741.8  9551.2 11679.6 12116.0 12177.5 12712.0 13312.7
```

Comment: To avoid multiple `gsub` you could use the `mgsub` package